# Removing first line from stdin and redirect to stdout

Tags: unix, stdout, stdin

i need to redirect all of the stdout of a program except the first line into a file.

Is there a common unix program that removes lines from stdin and spits the rest out to stdout?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Others have already mentioned "tail".  sed will also work:

```
sed 1d
```

As will Awk:

```
awk 'NR > 1'
```

Answer (score 5):

tail -n +2 -f -

Answer (score 0):

sed -e 1d < input > output